# can we use jquery ui with twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

can we use jquery ui with twitter-bootstrap ?

or it will lead to css conflicts

[jquery](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#)

[twitter-bootstrap](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Yep, it's ok. Go ahead. All jQuery-ui selectors should be prefixed.

Comment: You just asked largely the same question.

Comment: yes andrew i want to make it clearer

Comment: You can have a conflicts with function names button() method is good example. Just google about jQuery-ui and bootstrap conflicts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you don't use any of jQuery UI's stylesheets as your site may look screwy if you try to use different styles at once.

If you're going to use both, I suggest using Google's [hosted version of jQuery UI](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI) and the [Bootstrap v2.0 development branch](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) as your CSS, as the latter adds styles for functionality present in jQuery UI such as accordion effects and autocompletes.